# Iphone Speech Bubble

Tags: ios4, xcode4

It would be great if anyone could provide a tutorial or best approach to create a dynamic speech bubble in iphone. Here is the link of an application that already has a dynamic speech bubble built in - http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bubble-up-free/id364054415?mt=8 . Since I am starting to develop applications in xcode I am not sure whether to approach this using quartz 2d or open GL etc.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.uinnoblog.com/sms-bubble-ui-in-iphone-apps.html

Answer (score 2):

The previous approach is not really the good one where you can use only one image and use the advantage of the `stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth / topCapHeight` according with a `setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin` of an `UIImage` allowing to stretch an image by its width and/or height without stretching all angles...

In that case, your speech bubble image will be smaller, you'll need only one (instead of 9) AND your code will be really smaller...

Answer (score 2):

Here is good cocoa UI Component on GitHub: https://github.com/AlexBarinov/UIBubbleTableView